# I can’t install my npm on my react project

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1xlw.png)

When i try to install npm for my project i have showed this kind of error.

Comment: Please write an error as text instead of image. And please provide package.json info. This will help us to know your environments

Comment: This looks like your code just have wrong imports.